# Image size is incorrect from google cloud vision api (OCR) when using type: TEXT_DETECTION

Tags: ocr, google-cloud-vision

I am facing the problem that in some cases the image size in json is incorrect, when I am using type: "TEXT_DETECTION". I have figured out, that it happens when the image size differs only some pixels from a common ratio. 
I have tested an image in size:

```
 "width": 5152,
  "height": 2896,
```

Google cloud vision api reports an image size of

```
 "width": 5152,
  "height": 2895,
```

The strange thing is, that it always differs one pixel. But only if the image ratio is close to a common ratio. (16:9 in my case)
If you use e.g. an image size 5152 x 2890 the values from the API are correct.

This problem does not appear when you use  "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION".

I appreciate any idea how to fix this.

Thanks